# How to use VisualStudioCredential when creating StorageManagementClient and EventGridManagementClient

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-storage, azure-keyvault, azure-eventgrid

Recently, I discovered we can use [VisualStudioCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.visualstudiocredential?view=azure-dotnet) to authenticate with Azure Key Vault. See [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/README.md) GitHub page.

I'm trying to remove creds like client id, client secret, tenant id, etc. from the source code. I currently need these to instantiate an `AzureCredentials` in the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent` NuGet package.

Is it possible to use `VisualStudioCredential` for `StorageManagementClient` and `EventGridManagementClient`?

Comment: are you using this package [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage) ? Looks like it will be deprecated at a point and you should use the [Azure.ResourceManager.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Storage/) package. This last package supports `AzureCredentials`.

Comment: Correct. I'm using the first one you mentioned. What about the one for event grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid**](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid.) for `EventGridManagementClient`.There is a newer prerelease version of this package available.

You can also checkout this [***github***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/eventgrid/Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid/src/Generated) repro there is lot of models available in **Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid** and **EventGridManagementClient** is one of those.

Comment: I already use `EventGridManagementClient` from that package. Is there an example of `VisualStudioCredential` being used for this client?